# Can't Read System Fonts After Upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, fonts, gnome-shell

See the screenshot for an example of how all of my system fonts work. Fortunately, I can still read web pages and what I'm typing here.

Screenshot of desktop and open windows:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install the indispensable *(GNOME) Tweaks* if not installed already by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch Tweaks and go to *Fonts* section (most probably fourth from the top in the sidebar) and change all the fonts to working ones. See the screenshot below for reference:
[image]
This should fix the font rendering issue in window title, interface etc.

But you might still see the issue present in top bar, calendar and notification tray, system menu etc. In order to fix this you may change the shell theme in the *Appearance* section of Tweaks to one with supported font(s).
[image]

**Important note:** You won't be able to select any shell theme installed in your home directory by default. For that you'll have install and activate [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) shell extension first.

Comment: Perfect. I already had Gnome Tweak, so I just started it. The same radio buttons you had selected were selected, so I went to the top right and changed the Window and Interface fonts as suggested. All good now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, but I did notice that, though the programs and file browser seem to be fixed, the system menus are still not right. I've been in a hurry getting ready to go to work. I'll check back in when I get back. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jon By system menu do you mean the top bar, calendar and notification tray etc.? If yes, try changing the shell theme from Tweaks > Appearance section > Themes > Shell. I can help you to tweak your current shell theme and change the default font of it. But for that I need more info.

Comment: That got me going in the right direction. I didn't have the user themes shell extension installed. After I installed it, I had the option you just mentioned and I changed it to one of the ones that showed text. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Jon I'm glad to know that. I have appended the shell theme changing part to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did all steps recommended by [@pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) and it fixed the all font issues except the system menus.
According to [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/change-gnome-shell-font), the font of GNOME Shell's Top Bar is set in the `/usr/share/themes/<your-theme>/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`in `stage->font-family` section. In my case, it was `font-family: Futura Bk bt, Cantarell, Sans-Serif;` and these fonts were missing in my system. I installed the missing fonts, restarted Ubuntu and Voilà, everything works fine!