# Ubuntu terminal shows strange characters

Tags: command-line, 18.04, 20.04, gnome-terminal

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to version 20.04. Everything is fine, except for the terminal.

As shown in the attached image, it shows strange characters.

[image: Terminal showing unreadable text]

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972688/cant-read-system-fonts-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 installation gave my terminal all squares with 4 characters in them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239784/ubuntu-20-04-installation-gave-my-terminal-all-squares-with-4-characters-in-them)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a "bad font" problem. Open your preferences and choose one of the many options in there.